# Disable source code checkout in specific pipeline stages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a pipeline with multiple stages, and the source code is checked out automatically on all of them.  I do not need the source  code, but only published artifacts.

How can disable source code checkout for specific stages?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use Checkout option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout

Example:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:
- job: no_checkout
  steps:
  - checkout: none

  - script: echo Hello, world!
    displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- job: checkout
  steps:
  - script: echo Hello, world!
    displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

I found the documentation for the "checkout" step here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines

Comment: Is there a way to skip the items *Checkout* and *Post-job: Checkout* in the list presenting the stages, jobs and steps? Currently, I have *Initialize job*, *Checkout*, *Post-job: Checkout* and *Finalize Job* for every job. I'd like to see it only for the jobs that actually deal with the source code.

Comment: @KonradViltersten did you find out if that was possible?

Comment: @rufo Regrettably, no. Finally, I caved in and accepted that I'm not getting what I desire. Sucks...

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines) `checkout:` can (now) take a `condition:` which may help